# How to access array values outside for loop in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I'm working with array in PHP. My question is how to access PHP array values outside the for loop.

Here is the code.

```
<?php
$a = array("1","2");
for($i=0;$i<count($a);$i++){
#some core functionality DB related.
$val = $row['values'];
$b = explode(',',$val);
}
print_r($b);

$fin = array_combine($a,$b);
print_r($fin);
?>
```

I want to combine both the array, but I'm not getting array `b`. How to access the array values outside for loop?

Expected output:

```
Array ( [0] => 7 [1] => 6 ) // b array
Array ( [1] => 7 [2] => 6 ) // fin array
```

Comment: you have to combine array in side for loop because $b is taking last value fetched from database so i would suggest you combine value in for loop

Comment: when i try that array $a is getting looped twice. so its not working.

Comment: is $row['values']  having multiple value in code or not

Comment: yes it has and im assigning all values to $val

Comment: how you assigning all values because you are not concatenating the $val

Comment: please show sample input(s) for `$row['values']`

Comment: for($i=0;$i<2;$i++){
$val = $row['values']; // here i will get single digit number for every loop.(lets say for $i=0 $val = 1. $i=1 $val = 4)
}

Comment: when i'm concatenating. im getting 14 as $val value but explode function is not working with that $val. @AmitGaud

Comment: yeah right because in your string doesn't have comma values so you have to concatenate $val with comma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I keep staring at the original process and it seems unnecessarily convoluted.  Does this not do what you wish:

```
$a=["1","2"];
foreach($a as $k=>$v){
    // I don't know if you are using $k or $v in your DB actions
    // On 1st iteration, $k=0 & $v="1"; on 2nd: $k=1 & $v="2"
    $fin[$v]=explode(',',$row['values']);
}
var_export($fin);
```

If this is wrong please let me know how it is wrong so I can better understand the question.

Comment: @Vikky great.  I just want to mention that if this was my project, I'd probably look into optimizing my process so that I only need to make 1 call to the database, rather than a call for each value in `$a`.   ...I'll leave you to think about that possibility.

Comment: yes absolutely @mick. for simple understanding i have mention $a array, but in real time i get this from db and convert it to array. 
thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Try appending all the results to the original array.
Something like this.

```
<?php
$a = array("1","2");

for($i=0;$i<count($a);$i++){
#some core functionality DB related.
$val = $row['values'];
$temp_array = explode(',',$val);
    for($j=0;$j<sizeof($temp_array);$j++){
        array_push($a,$temp_array[$j]);
    }
}
print_r($a);

?>
```

Comment: instead of directly assigning the explode value you can, use array_push to keep all the values in $b, you can edit the code to add the below value, array_push($b, explode(',',$val)); instead of $b = explode(',',$val);

Comment: Im getting the last value in the array @nandan.
when i try your approach im getting blank page Aoxi

Comment: @nandan im using for loop for DB only as im getting values from a table. and i'm trying to assign that value to $a array as key=> value pair

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong you are looking for this code with above what I have discussed with you

```
<?php
$a = array("1","2");
$b = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($a);$i++){
#some core functionality DB related.
$b[] = $row['values'];
}
print_r($b);

$fin = array_combine($a,$b);
print_r($fin);

?>
```

Comment: yes but only thing is we have to declare $b = array(); before for loop to access the array. rest is same
thanks @amit

Comment: @Vikky I have changed